# Openstack-Ironic:Networking is not working properly in Ironic nodes

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Im trying to use the ml2 network of openstack for ironic node created with IPMI driver,but it was not connecting properly and causing the error given below when I validate the node created

====

```
network    | False  | Unexpected exception, traceback saved into log by ironic conductor service that is running on dr: Unexpected exception for 10.0.2.20/v2.0/networks?fields=id&name=net1: Invalid URL '10.0.2.20/v2.0/networks?fields=id&name=net1': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://10.0.2.20/v2.0/networks?fields=id&name=net1?
```

====

Answer (score 0):

It seems the neutron endpoint is misconfigured in the ironic configuration file or misconfigured in the keystone endpoint.